# How is it possible to know whether my computer has been infected by a Macro Virus?

Tags: security, libreoffice, malware

Today, I have received a new `.doc` document and wanted to open it using LibreOffice (Version 5.1.6.2).
The following warning message was displayed:

> This document contains macros.
>
> Macros may contain viruses. Execution of macros is disabled due 
>   to the current macro security setting in Tools -> Options -> LibreOffice -> Security (3 - High). Therefore, some functionality may not be available.

Then, I had no option of preventing myself from opening the document.
Although the execution of macros is disabled, I am still worried about the possible presence of the micro virus on my Ubuntu (16.04.2 LTS) computer.

How is it possible to know whether my computer has been infected by a macro virus?

Comment: That message is shown for any file with macros with the current default settings, exactly as stated in the warning. Macros in itself is a feature, not a problem. However, it's an infection vector (allows code execution), hence the warning. The chances of infection are arguably very low. If it comes from a reputable (and responsible security wise) source it's probably OK. But if it's some form to collect money from a Nigerian Prince desperately in need of your help, ignore, delete email and attachments and update your spam filter.

Answer (score 0):

The only absolutely certain way to ensure a macro is not a virus, is to examine its source code or just not use it...

**LQ queue reviewers: That's it!**